# How are Lie groups and polynomial resolvents related?

Tags: lie-groups, polynomials, ho.history-overview

I came across the following sentence in Stevenhagen and Lenstra's wonderful little article [Chebotarëv and his density theorem](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Ehwl/papers/cheb.pdf):

> Nikolai's interest in [polynomial] resolvents led him to study Lie groups.

I have to say I don't really see how this would happen, and I'm curious what the connection that led Cebotarev from studying resolvents to studying Lie groups was. Does anyone know? I would be interested even in an educated guess by someone who knows the two areas mathematically, but perhaps not the specific historical context.

Comment: Although you are interested in a mathematical, and not just an historical, answer, this may also be appropriate for [HSMSE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) (of course with an explicit mention of the cross-post on both posts).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I actually wasn't aware that HSMSE existed. I'll edit here and cross-post there to get to a wider audience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [The Resolvent Problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.04718) (1947) Chebotarev links the number of parameters in the resolvent to a Lie group theory conjecture by Cartan:

> One could hope that Cartan’s hypothesis is not true. [The hypothesis on the number of parameters of simple continuous groups, implying that an
> equation of the $n$-th degree has a resolvent with at least $n-3$
> parameters.] Then the number of parameters in the
> resolvent could be reduced by more than three parameters. However, in
> 1938 I was able to prove the correctness of Cartan’s conjecture [1].

[1] N. Tschebotaröw. [Über irreguläre Darstellungen von halbeinfachen Lieschen Gruppen](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1939__6__103_0) [On irregular representations of semi-simple Lie groups] (1938).